# New manhwa in which a female heir with a bad adoptive sister dies in a car wreck and regresses back in time

Tags: story-identification, manga

A newish manga to me (because it was still ongoing) about a female regression.

She finds out that her adoptive sister takes over the family and possibly even plans for the female lead (FL) to die. The FL dies in a car wreck, then when she regresses, decides to be model student so that nothing could be used against her. Her mom is in politics or something like that. The mom adopts the sister for charity work, but the FL decided to act better than her, etc. There was also something about her going to a school later on.

Comment: I take it this was set in the modern world? And do you recall the hair colour of the female lead or the adoptive sister?